# Objective C When running tests: Class defined without specifying a base class

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoapods

I have no idea what is going on as I am fairly new to objective c and IOS dev.

When i try to run my tests, using the default testing framework i get the following error:

```
        ..../Pods/Expecta/src/matchers/EXPMatchers+beCloseTo.m:4:1: 
Class 'EXPFixCategoriesBugEXPMatcher_beCloseToWithinMatcher' 
    defined without specifying a base class
```

The following peice of code generates the issue (however it is not mine, I believe it is a peice from one of the libraries I am using through pods):

```
#import "EXPMatchers+beCloseTo.h"
#import "EXPMatcherHelpers.h"

EXPMatcherImplementationBegin(_beCloseToWithin, (id expected, id within)) {
  prerequisite(^BOOL{
    return [actual isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] &&
        [expected isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] &&
        ([within isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] || (within == nil));
  });

  match(^BOOL{
        double actualValue = [actual doubleValue];
        double expectedValue = [expected doubleValue];

        if (within != nil) {
            double withinValue = [within doubleValue];
            double lowerBound = expectedValue - withinValue;
            double upperBound = expectedValue + withinValue;
            return (actualValue >= lowerBound) && (actualValue <= upperBound);
        } else {
            double diff = fabs(actualValue - expectedValue);
            actualValue = fabs(actualValue);
            expectedValue = fabs(expectedValue);
            double largest = (expectedValue > actualValue) ? expectedValue : actualValue;
            return (diff <= largest * FLT_EPSILON);
        }
  });

  failureMessageForTo(^NSString *{
    if (within) {
      return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"expected %@ to be close to %@ within %@",
              EXPDescribeObject(actual), EXPDescribeObject(expected), EXPDescribeObject(within)];
    } else {
      return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"expected %@ to be close to %@",
              EXPDescribeObject(actual), EXPDescribeObject(expected)];
    }
  });

  failureMessageForNotTo(^NSString *{
    if (within) {
      return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"expected %@ not to be close to %@ within %@",
              EXPDescribeObject(actual), EXPDescribeObject(expected), EXPDescribeObject(within)];
    } else {
      return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"expected %@ not to be close to %@",
              EXPDescribeObject(actual), EXPDescribeObject(expected)];
    }
  });
}
EXPMatcherImplementationEnd
```

My POD files looks as follows:

```
platform :ios, 6.0
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.20.0rc'

# Include optional Testing and Search components
pod 'RestKit/Testing', '~> 0.20.0rc'
pod 'RestKit/Search', '~> 0.20.0rc'


target :MTPROJTESTS do
  pod 'Expecta',     '~> 0.2.3'   # expecta matchers
  # pod 'Specta',      '~> 0.1.11'  # specta bdd framework
end
```

NEW ERROR after updating cocoa pods and EXPECTA: `ld: library not found for -lPods-test
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Error:

```
Ld /Users/AUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYIOSPROJProject-cmxbzcbzjfbvgncspsalqnjvlova/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYIOSPROJProjectTests.xctest/MYIOSPROJProjectTests normal i386
cd /Users/AUSER/Documents/Dev/MYIOSPROJProject/MYIOSPROJProject
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/AUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYIOSPROJProject-cmxbzcbzjfbvgncspsalqnjvlova/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/AUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYIOSPROJProject-cmxbzcbzjfbvgncspsalqnjvlova/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/AUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYIOSPROJProject-cmxbzcbzjfbvgncspsalqnjvlova/Build/Intermediates/MYIOSPROJProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYIOSPROJProjectTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/MYIOSPROJProjectTests.LinkFileList -bundle_loader /Users/AUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYIOSPROJProject-cmxbzcbzjfbvgncspsalqnjvlova/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYIOSPROJProject.app/MYIOSPROJProject -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -framework XCTest -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lPods-test -lPods-MYIOSPROJProjectTests -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/AUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYIOSPROJProject-cmxbzcbzjfbvgncspsalqnjvlova/Build/Intermediates/MYIOSPROJProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYIOSPROJProjectTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/MYIOSPROJProjectTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/AUSER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYIOSPROJProject-cmxbzcbzjfbvgncspsalqnjvlova/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYIOSPROJProjectTests.xctest/MYIOSPROJProjectTests
```

I hope someone out there has a clue :)

Comment: You probably declared a class using `@interface` in one of your .h files without specifying a base class (i.e. Look for a missing colon+base class in a line that should look like this: `@interface MyClass : BaseClass`).

Comment: The solution compiles when I run it or build it - its only when I run a test (and I only have one test) that it fails...

Comment: can your post your podfile? also try use new version of Expecta

Comment: Maybe you need to add -ObjC or even -all_load to "Other Linker Flags" of the target.

Comment: @NoilPaw try one, the other and then both of the "Other Linker Flags" and neither solved the problem.

Comment: @BryanChen added podfile above.

Comment: try new version of `Expecta`? which is '0.2.3'

Comment: Updated cocoapods and EXPECTA.. Now i get the following: "ld: library not found for -lPods-test"

Comment: If that library declares a new base class you would get that error message from Clang. Creating a new base class comes with the assumption you know how to handle it. You probably need the same handling in your test code. It's covered elsewhere I'm sure.

Comment: @uchuugaka I am not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the new linker error: Xcode likes to add a new build target for testing, so make sure all the appropriate files (e.g., your .m source files, your static libraries, your frameworks) are set to be included in the test build target. You can do this by selecting the file in the Project Navigator and looking at the "Target Membership" section in the File Inspector pane; make sure the box is checked for the test build target. Also, in your project settings you can select the test build target and go to Build Phases and look at "Link Binary With Libraries" to ensure the appropriate libraries are linked.

Comment: I have added all the .h and .m files from my non-test proj to the test project. This error still persists... Can you give me anymore guidance on what exactly needs to be included?

Comment: I'm not sure my solution will help then, but be sure to make the distinction between *adding your files to your project* and *including them in your build target*: these are two different concepts. Simply adding your files to your project does not necessarily include them in all your build targets. To check your build targets, select a file in your project navigator and then look at "Target Membership" in the File Inspector pane. Also, to check your frameworks for a particular target click on your project at the top of the Project Navigator, select the correct target, and go to build phases.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like `EXPFixCategoriesBugEXPMatcher_beCloseToWithinMatcher`'s base class is in the prefix header for your app project, but not imported in `EXPFixCategoriesBugEXPMatcher_beCloseToWithinMatcher`'s .h file. You should generally import the base class at the top of your class's interface file:

```
#import "YourBaseClassHere.h"

@interface EXPFixCategoriesBugEXPMatcher_beCloseToWithinMatcher : YourBaseClassHere

// The rest of your class here

@end
```